# dynamic dropdown populate in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two dropdowns and a submit button on a rails form HAML page. I would like dropdown 2's content be populated dynamically based on dropdown 1 selection, and submit the form based on both of two dropdown's selected values.

I know how to do the submit part, but I'm a bit lost on the dynamic rendering for dropdowns. I can let dropdown 1 to call a controller method to update db (used by dropdown 2) and redirect to the form. This doesn't seem to perform well. Any suggestions on how to write the two dropdowns?

Comment: The excellent Chris Oliver at GoRails did a great video on how to do this with all the modern Rails capabilities... hotwire and stimulus. It's here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReZS6wfh3lo

Comment: is there a way doing so without using either libraries?

Comment: Yes, of course. Broadly speaking, you need to trigger an ajax request "onChange" of dropdown 1, and the response is a rails html partial containing the "options_for_select" for dropdown 2. Then the response handler inserts the received response into dropdown2. There should not be any database update involved. My recommendation is to do it the modern way with Hotwire and stimulus, it's less work and cleaner and it's now "The Rails Way(tm)".